# After searching files, Dash stops searching applications?

Tags: unity-dash

If I press <kbd>Super</kbd> I usually start typing and it searches for both applications and files. But if I open a file after searching and try to press super again, it only searches for files and not applications. Is this a glitch? How can I fix it?

Yes it is still on the "Home" Scope. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

You can try resetting unity with below command

```
unity --reset
```

In case you are using  14.04 , above command is deprecated and you will need to install unity-tweak-tool by

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

and reset Unity with

```
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

BTW  have you tried synapse ? ,  very good alternative to unity-dash

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:synapse-core/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synapse
```

hit Ctrl + Space  , and search anything you want